# iOS doesNotRecognizeSelector in CoreFoundation

Tags: ios, crash, foundation, core-foundation

I'm getting crash from our custom keyboard extension that shows `doesNotRecognizeSelector` in the report but the code that's crashing isn't mine... it's in Foundation/CoreFoundation. Here's the crash report...

```
Incident Identifier: B7818....
CrashReporter Key:   57ce8....
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,2
Process:             MyApp Keyboard [7390]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB6EA.....B37/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp Keyboard.appex/MyApp Keyboard
Identifier:          com.MyDomain.MyApp.MyApp-Keyboard
Version:             288 (3.12)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.MyDomain.MyApp.MyApp-Keyboard [710]


Date/Time:           2018-03-07 16:51:29.4017 -0500
Launch Time:         2018-03-07 16:51:28.3872 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.6 (15D100)
Baseband Version:    3.42.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  4

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation      0x18146b164 __exceptionPreprocess + 124 (NSException.m:166)
1   libobjc.A.dylib     0x1806b4528 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:521)
2   CoreFoundation      0x181478628 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 140 (NSObject.m:322)
3   CoreFoundation      0x181470b10 ___forwarding___ + 1380 (NSForwarding.m:3220)
4   CoreFoundation      0x181355ccc _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   Foundation      0x181df65e4 -[NSExtensionContext _willPerformHostCallback:] + 180 (NSExtensionContext.m:838)
6   Foundation      0x181df32d4 __105-[_NSExtensionContextVendor _beginRequestWithExtensionItems:listenerEndpoint:withContextUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 780 (NSExtensionContext.m:268)
7   libdispatch.dylib   0x180deaa54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:994)
8   libdispatch.dylib   0x180deaa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:502)
9   libdispatch.dylib   0x180df496c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528 (inline_internal.h:2500)
10  libdispatch.dylib   0x180df52fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340 (queue.c:5302)
11  libdispatch.dylib   0x180df5d20 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404 (queue.c:5920)
12  libdispatch.dylib   0x180dfe03c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644 (source.c:2529)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x181092f1c _pthread_wqthread + 932 (pthread.c:2207)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x181092b6c start_wqthread + 4
```

I can see the `doesNotRecognizeSelector` at line 2 and the nearest thing in the stack is `NSExtensionContext _willPerformHostCallback`. I looked through all the threads in the report and nothing shows anything from our code. I searched our codebase and I don't see any code where we override `willPerformHostCallback` or anything derived from `NSExtensionContext` for that matter.

Can anybody see what the deal is here?

TIA, Mike

Comment: Is there any message in the debug console or the device console that says **which** selector is unrecognized?

Comment: @PhillipMills These are crash reports I'm getting from iTunes connect. They were retrieved from devices in the field, not something I was running in the debugger.